# How to remove &nbsp; in angular js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

The angular expression is `{{ notification.noti_val }}`.
The value stored in the expression is `saha &nbsp;like&nbsp;own&nbsp;wall`.

How can I remove the `&nbsp;` characters?

Comment: Did you tried `str.replace(/&nb sp/g,"");`

Comment: I did this {{notification.noti_val.replace(/&nb sp/g,"");}} but got error like Error: [$parse:lexerr] Lexer Error: Unexpected next character  at columns 31-31 [&] in expression [notification.noti_val.replace(/&nb sp/g,"");].And there is no space between nb and sp.I did that because the site was showing as space

Comment: Try escaping the `&`. `(/\&nbsp;/g, ' ')`

Comment: Sorry didnt work ; did {{notification.noti_val.replace(/\&nbsp;/g, ' ')}}; Error showing:Error: [$parse:lexerr] Lexer Error: Unexpected next character  at columns 31-31 [\] in expression [notification.noti_val.replace(/\ /g, ' ')].Note:SO site is not showing the '\' in the []

Comment: Lex thanks man for your time.Dont know why replace isnt working.Have to question this in other thread.But many thanks

Comment: Use backticks (\`) when quoting code. Like: `this`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify your value as safe html. In angular you can use `$sce`service to do so. I have created this [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/nanohow/edit?html,js,console,output) explaining the use case and it fixes your issue

Comment: angular expression:{{trustAsHtml(notification.noti_val)}}   service declared in controller:app.controller('NotificationCtrl', function($scope, $http, $ionicLoading, $state, $stateParams, 
    $ionicPopup, profile, $sce){.....      Inside the controller :$scope.trustAsHtml = function(notificationText){
            return $sce.trustAsHtml(notificationText);
        }; still shows ujjal saha&nb sp;share&nb sp;own&nb sp;wall;Note add the space between nb and sp due to site formatting

Comment: Ok got it.Had to slightly change the html format to the one as in the jsbin but works.Thanks man.